# Math Help on number theory Modular Arithmetic Systems

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can Someone please help me with this question it is coming up in my AOPS Alcumus and I don't know how to do it can someone show me please

Suppose that $x$ is an integer that satisfies the following congruences:\begin{align*}
3+x &\equiv 2^2 \pmod{3^3} \\
5+x &\equiv 3^2 \pmod{5^3} \\
7+x &\equiv 5^2 \pmod{7^3}
\end{align*}What is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $105$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Notice that $105=3\times 5 \times 7$. We know that

$\begin{align*}
x &\equiv 2^2\equiv 1 \pmod{3} \\
x &\equiv 3^2\equiv 4 \pmod{5} \\
x &\equiv 5^2\equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}$

Can you complete it now using the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

> Notice that $x \equiv1 \equiv 4\pmod{3}$ and so $x$ is $4$ modulo  $3,5$ and $7$. Hence $x=105k+4$ and the remainder is $4$.